# Запрет преобразования int в строку.

Tags: qt5

```
unsigned i = 100;
QString str("text" + i); //textd
```

Должно быть text100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он и не преобразовывал int в строку, он просто добавил символ. 100 - это код символа d.
Твоя проблема как раз в том, что надо было перевести i в строку, а не запрещать это. :)
Для перевода обычно используется [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), но всё же более предпочтителен [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/).

Comment: Зачем таким извратом заниматься, когда есть QString::number() ? =)

    unsigned i = 100;
    QString("text") +  QString::number(i);